# Merge multiple Anaconda environments (accidentally created a second, and installed several modules)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have two environments within Anaconda, and I would like to remove one, but preserve the various modules installed in each. 
One is base (root), and the other is Miniconda3, in which I've installed the plotly module. This was not intentional. I am not planning to need multiple environments in the foreseeable future.
Some Jupyter notebooks only run after switching to the Miniconda3 environment (otherwise the error of not finding the plotly module in the base (root) environment)
Another acceptable solution might be to set the Miniconda3 environment to default.
Another acceptable solution - install modules into the base environment.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `conda env --list` please?

Comment: What do you mean by _preserve the various modules installed in each._ ? _One is base (root), and the other is Miniconda3, in which I've installed the plotly module._ Wait, can you clarify what you mean? Miniconda3 is not an environment. _I am not planning to need multiple environments in the foreseeable future._ You absolutely should use multiple environments, that's half of what Conda does.

Comment: _Some Jupyter notebooks only run after switching to the Miniconda3 environment (otherwise the error of not finding the plotly module in the base (root) environment)_ Unless I'm misunderstanding something, isn't that entirely to be expected, and the point of using virtual environments?

Comment: @darthbith - I tried the "conda env --list" in the command line, while in my "base" environment and the "--list" was an unrecognized element.

Comment: @AMC - some clarification - yes, I get that this is the point of using virtual environments, but I was still just starting out, and to have some modules (the ones I'm intending on using) NOT work in the default environment is a bit of a pain. The Miniconda3 was what I called the second environment, perhaps a rookie mistake. I was hoping to find a solution that didn't involve wiping the entire setup. For now, I'm just trying to remember to change the environment every time, before I start up Jupyter Notebook. I'd be happy to use multiple environments, once I get that far, but not yet.

Comment: @darthbith I tried this (sorry, not sure how to make this more legible)
(base) C:\Users\jrichardson>conda-env list
Output:
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\jrichardson\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
RStudio                  C:\Users\jrichardson\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\
envs\RStudio
                         C:\Users\jrichardson\Miniconda3
The RStudio stuff was added later, and hasn't been used yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [conda-merge](https://github.com/amitbeka/conda-merge). According to the developer, it preserves dependencies between environments.

Install it from this command: `conda install -c conda-forge conda-merge`

Then use the following command to merge the environments:

`conda-merge FILE1 FILE2 ... FILE-N > OUTPUT-FILE`

Comment: Would this work to just merge everything into the root environment? I don't really need multiple environments at this point - perhaps use BASE for FILE1 and for FILE-N, in your example?

Comment: Yes FILE here means conda environment name and OUTPUT FILE means the resulting environment name.

Comment: i Have 3 environment env_1, env_2, env_3 and when i execute conda-merge env_1 env_2 env_3 > new_env is giving FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'env_1'. Can you help